# How do I return a modified vector in c++?

Tags: c++

Why does (return A;) not work? The error I get is "No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called."

How do I return the newly sorted vector?

```
int sort(vector <int> A, int n)
{
    if( n >= 2 && n <= 43)
    {
        //sort vector
        for(int j=2; j<=n; j++)
        {
            int tmp = A[j];
            int i = j-1;
            while (-1<i && tmp < A[i])
            {
                A[i+1] = A[i];
                i--;
            }
            A[i+1] = tmp;
        }
    }

    return A;
}
```

Comment: Because A is not an `int` as is your function type.

Comment: Usually what you do is call `std::sort` with a pair of iterators. Then you don't have to worry about writing bugs and fixing them.

Comment: The return type says `int`. There's no conversion from `vector` to `int`.

Comment: I dont understand. I want to return the modified vector A, which is already an int. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: A `vector<int>` is not an `int`.

Comment: well i mean its of type int. shouldnt i be able to return the vector A somehow?

Comment: No it is **not of type int**. It is of type `vector<int>`.

Comment: omg. thank you. i overlooked this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with one of the following two ways to solve this problem:

1) Change return type of the function to vector

```
vector<int> sort(vector <int> A, int n){
    // body of function
}
```

2) Pass reference to the vector as parameter. It will affect the function prototype as follows

```
int sort(vector <int> &A, int n){
    // body of function
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. I feel so dumb. cant believe i missed this.

Comment: You can also use the complete code given below. If you still have any confusing. I have tested that :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your method declaration to:

`vector <int> sort(vector <int> A, int n)`

You are trying to return a `vector<int>` when your return type is currently `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only return values of the declared type from your functions in C / C++.
Anyway, in your case the proper choice is not returning the vector, but passing it in by reference, so you can modify the original vector. Change your prototype thus:

```
void sort(vector<int>& A)
```

I also removed `n`, because the vector knows its size.

Also, if you do not want to change it, for efficiency consider passing a `const`-qualified reference to the original instead. Don't do that for small easily copied basic types though.

Comment: thank you so much. I feel so dumb. cant believe i missed this.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
int sort(vector <int> A, int n)
```

to

```
vector<int> sort(vector <int> A, int n)
```

if u would like to return A.

or you can use pass byref instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code .

```
vector<int> sort(vector <int> A, int n)
{
    if( n >= 2 && n <= 43)
    {
        //sort vector
        for(int j=2; j<=n; j++)
        {
            int tmp = A[j];
            int i = j-1;
            while (-1<i && tmp < A[i])
            {
                A[i+1] = A[i];
                i--;
            }
            A[i+1] = tmp;
        }
    }

    return A;
}
```